# OCR Training Font Licence

Tags: ocr, training-data

I am trying to find out if anyone may be able to help with this.

I am training an ocr to recognise a certain font, the font I want it to recognise is a commercial font that needs a licence to embed it in an app.

My question is do I need a licence to train the ocr to recognise it? I won't be displaying the font or embedding the font anywhere else only training the font to be recognised.